# proof of derivative using definition

Tags: calculus

Use the definition to show that the function $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\ge 0$ is differentiable at each $x\in (0,+\infty)$.
My solution is

$x_0= (0,\infty +$)

($\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}}{x-x_0}$)

$\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}}{x-x_0}*\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}=
\frac{x-x_0}{(x-x_0)(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0})}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}$ which as $x$ approaches $x_0= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}}$

I though I was done but I was told the definition to use was $f(x)-f(x_0)=h(x) (x-x_0)$
Any ideas on where i went wrong?

Comment: That definition (as written) doesn't have enough information (for me, at least) to see what you're supposed to do. Can you edit your post to include the full definition?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} 
\frac{\sqrt{x + \Delta{x}}-\sqrt{x}} {\Delta x} 
\frac{\sqrt{x + \Delta{x}} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x + \Delta{x}} + \sqrt{x}} =
\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} 
\frac{{x + \Delta{x}}-{x}} {\Delta x {(\sqrt{x + \Delta{x}}} + \sqrt x )} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
$

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're supposed to use this definition, though I can't quite tell for sure.

> Given a set $E\subseteq\Bbb R,$ a point $x_0\in E$ such that $(x_0-c,x_0+c)\subseteq E$ for some $c>0,$ and a function $f:E\to\Bbb R,$ we say that $f$ is *differentiable at* $x_0$ if there is a number $L$ and a function $h$ defined on $(x_0-c,x_0+c)$ such that $$f(x)-f(x_0)=L\cdot(x-x_0)+h(x)\tag{1}$$ and $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{h(x)}{x-x_0}=0.\tag{2}$$ We say that $L$ is *the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$*, denoted by $L=f'(x_0).$

Now, you've already figured out that $$f'(x_0)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}}$$ for each $x_0\in(0,\infty),$ in your case. Now, we need to show that $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for some function $h$ when we substitute $L=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}}.$ Fortunately, since we need $(1)$ to hold after substitution, it's easy to see that we require $$h(x)=f(x)-f(x_0)-L\cdot(x-x_0)=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}}(x-x_0).$$ Then $$\frac{h(x)}{x-x_0}=\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_0}}{x-x_0}-\frac1{2\sqrt{x_0}}=\frac1{\sqrt x +\sqrt{x_0}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{x_0}},$$ so to show that $(2)$ holds, it suffices to show that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac1{\sqrt x +\sqrt{x_0}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{x_0}}.$$